# How do I animate a series of animations on click?

Tags: jquery

I have a series of elements that I want to animate one by one on click. The first one animates, but the next one will not. What am I missing here?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewtamala/xC95V/16/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {  
        $('.slide').next().animate({"top" : "5000"}, 500);
    })   
});
```

Comment: $('.slide').next() is always selecting for the same `li` you need a way to keep track of which one is currently visible.

Comment: I don't know exactly what your going for, but this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/xC95V/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xC95V/22/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = $(".slide").length;

    $('.button').click(function() {  
        i--;
        $('.slide').eq(i).animate({"top" : "5000"}, 500);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I did some research on .length and .eq and I can make sense of your solution. My only further questions would be the purpose of "i--;". What does this piece do?

Comment: it decreases the index of the `.slide` element to be hidden on every click - 3, 2, 1, 0

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isn't doing what you think.

```
$('.slide').next().animate({"top" : "5000"}, 500);
```

`$('.slide')`   This is selecting all elements off class slide.  That means it's selecting, "slide blue", "slide red", "slide yellow" and "slide black".

`$('.slide').next()`  This takes the next sibling (if any) of all the slides you selected, namely "slide blue", "slide red", and "slide yellow".

Your animate is acting on blue, red, and yellow, leaving nothing but black on the top.

Subsequent button pushes do nothing, because black has no siblings left.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

add an up class to all your elements (just to mark them as up) then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



    $('.button').click(function(){  
        var slide = $('.slide.up').last();
        slide.toggleClass('up');
        slide.animate({"top" : "5000"}, 500);
    })

});
```

Tested and it works on your jsFiddle as expected